# how to give zod object schema custom error message, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I want zod object to have custom error message .
I am using custom hook form in react js.

```
sub_facility: z
.object({
  id: z.number(),
  facility_name: z.string(),
  depth: z.number(),
  parentId: z.number().optional().nullable(),
  matchTerms: z.string().array(),
})
.required(),
```

I tried to give string to require("Facility please")
but the typescript says 0 arguments and it doesnot work

```
sub_facility: z
.object({
  id: z.number(),
  facility_name: z.string(),
  depth: z.number(),
  parentId: z.number().optional().nullable(),
  matchTerms: z.string().array(),
})
.required(),
```

Comment: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/master/ERROR_HANDLING.md